# Angular2 + AFrame: registerComponent

Tags: angular, require, aframe, stereo-3d

I have gotten A-Frame working well in my Angular2 project, however now I'm trying to register 3rd party packages.  Specifically the "aframe-stereo-component" I have the npm, but now I need to implement this bit of script.

```
<script>
  var AFRAME = require('aframe');
  var stereoComponent = require('aframe-stereo-component').stereo_component;
  var stereocamComponent = require('aframe-stereo-component').stereocam_component;

  AFRAME.registerComponent('stereo', stereoComponent);
  AFRAME.registerComponent('stereocam', stereocamComponent);
</script>
```

I added it to my index.html however it didn't seem to work.  This is a bit over my head and I could use the help.  Props to Oscarmarinmiro for [aframe-stereo-component on Git](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component)

Comment: Adding NPM `require('foo')` statements directly in a browser won't work, that approach requires a bundler like Browserify or Webpack. If you're not already using a module bundler, I'd just include a `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component/v0.3.1/dist/aframe-stereo-component.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am using Angular-CLI I have the two packages implemented like this.
    <!-- Added scripts for A frame  -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.js"></script>

    <script src="aframe-stereo-component.js.min.js"></script>

I see now that the requires aren't proper, but I'm still trying to figure out how to register components on A-Frame.  Right now I'm trying to understand how to make my own components from the docs.
"AFRAME.registerComponent('position', {
  schema: { type: 'vec3' },
  update: function () {
    var object3D = this.el.object3D;
...

Comment: I tried to use the import <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-com‌​ponent/v0.3.1/dist/a‌​frame-stereo-compone‌​nt.min.js"></script> @Don_McCurdy however, i got a 404 error in my console.  I've been at this all day >,<.  I must be missing something.

Comment: My link is broken somehow, I think it may be related to comment formatting. I'll post an answer with the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-com‌​ponent/6db3472a/dist‌​/aframe-stereo-compo‌​nent.min.js"  .... 
Was the correct import for the component.  Thanks @Don_McCurdy

Answer (score 2):

Adding NPM require('foo') statements directly in a browser won't work, that approach requires a bundler like Browserify or Webpack. If you're not already using a module bundler, I'd just include a script directly.

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component/v0.3.1/dist/aframe-stereo-component.min.js"></script>
```

If this script is included after A-Frame itself, it should 'just work' without requiring you to register anything. You can confirm this by checking `AFRAME.components['stereo']` in the JS console.

One side note, it's better not to remove the "https://" or "http://" prefixes from URLs used in this way.

Comment: `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component/6db3472a/dist/aframe-stereo-component.min.js"> </script> ` seemed to do the trick!  I checked "AFRAME.components['stereo']" and it was correct, so I'm off to the races.  Thank you  very much.  ミ^ᆺ^彡